# Grep square brackets, unix bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need to grep on txt file, for instance this is the file

```
[Hey my][aaaaaaa]
bla bla bla
bla bla
```

I want the first line where the words "Hey my" apears

So this is my code:

```
grep "Hey my" file.txt | head -n 1
```

but this will give all the first line, I need the first square brackets only

How I do that..?

Comment: do you need the square brackets also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cut`:

```
grep "Hey my" test | cut -d[ -f1-2
```

This will work on almost any Unix (Mac OS, BSD) or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the `-o` flag with GNU `grep`.  It will show only the parts of the line that match.  Also, `-m` will stop after some number of matches, so you could do those 2 commands as

```
grep -m 1 -o "Hey my" file.txt
```

Which will just give you "Hey my" as a result.

If you want the brackets too, since brackets define character classes in regex you probably want to add the `-F` flag to tell `grep` not to use regex like

```
grep -m1 -oF "[Hey my]" file.txt
```